# Spring Data Neo4j Transaction does not work with Neo4j server

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm working on spring-data and neo4j and I encountered a problem with transaction.

Here is my spring configuration :

```
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="fr.simple.nosqltest" />

<neo4j:repositories base-package="fr.simple.nosqltest"/>

<!-- Neo4j configuration (creates Neo4jTemplate) -->
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />


<!-- For unit tests : 
With these two following lines (uncomment them to test), datas are well recorded   in directory database
and rollback on failed transaction works -->
<!--    <neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/neo4j-db"/>  -->
<!--     <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/> -->

<!--    But in a real world, I would like to use a Neo4J server. -->
<!--    Rollbacks are not working with this following configuration :  -->
<bean id="graphDatabaseService"
    class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
    <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data/" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

As I said in comments in my spring configuration file, transaction works well when I'm running a unit test with:

```
neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/neo4j-db"
```

but not when I try to run the same code but using a real neo4j server. I tried lot's of combinations on how to write the `tx:annotation-driven` tag but nothing is working. I can't find a solution on the internet, but all examples that I found work without a neo4j server.

Can you please help me to configure transaction with this framework. I posted my code on github: https://github.com/clement94/spring-neo4j-test

Comment: What exactly is your question? One useful way to ask for help is to state 1) What you did, 2) What you expected to happen, 3) What actually happened, and 4) What you have tried so far to remedy the problem. As your question stands it's very difficult to answer because it's not clear what you want to do and what the problem is that you encounter.

Comment: There are no real transactions with Neo4j server, only with the embedded version of Neo4j. For the Neo4j 2.0 integration this might change, as Neo4j 2.0 offers a transactional cypher endpoint.

Comment: Yes I finnaly see that in documentation. As I really need transactions, do you think it's a good thing to use an embedded database in production like I do in my unit tests ? What is the limit size of node/relationship numbers and disk space with embedded ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Michal Hunger - I'm using Neo4J2.0.1 and SDN-3.0.0.RELEASE, and I'm connecting to the DB by using the SpringRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/"). You mentioned on your comment, that not having a transactions might change, well, did it change already? Do you support real transactions when not using the embedded DB?